# Using Figma- Tkinter Designer Using Command Prompt- Error

Tags: python, shell, user-interface, tkinter, figma

I have created a simple GUI design Figma and now I want to convert it to python code using tkinter designer. I have copied the URL of the figma design and the token as well. I have put theses as inputs in the command prompt as below (tkinter+space+URL+space+token)

```
tkinter URL token
```

However, when I run it I get the below error:

```
usage: tkdesigner [-h] [-o OUTPUT] [-f] file_url token
tkdesigner: error: the following arguments are required: token
't' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Correction: tkdesigner URL token

Comment: Post a [mre]. And if you solved the problem, why not answer your own question?

Comment: I did not solve the problem! that was a typo in the question

Comment: Then why not edit the question? Anyway, provide the command line that reproduces the error.

Comment: tkdesigner https://www.figma.com/file/00FHTbNQ7HShsmEdcJjLKQ/Try?node-id=0%3A1&t=9ggzkAheahPFBZlk-1 figd_4kWDuv4OcO6oaiu-Tf7KnqwvnQoNDgMWIaCLygTm

Comment: Try to quote the url with double quotes.